# Flutter - App wont build. org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.resolve.SearchUtilsKt.getKSerializerConstructorMarker(SearchUtils.kt:64)

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle, build

Unable to build my flutter app. Seems to be a kotlin issue but can't work out what. I assumed it was a Kotlin/Gradle plugin/version issue but no luck.

```
e: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.resolve.SearchUtilsKt.getKSerializerConstructorMarker(SearchUtils.kt:64)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.resolve.KSerializerDescriptorResolver.createLoadConstructorDescriptor(KSerializerDescriptorResolver.kt:340)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.extensions.SerializationResolveExtension.generateSyntheticSecondaryConstructors(SerializationResolveExtension.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.addSyntheticSecondaryConstructors(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:500)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.doGetConstructors(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:495)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.access$doGetConstructors(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:52)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope$secondaryConstructors$1.invoke(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:490)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope$secondaryConstructors$1.invoke(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:490)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:527)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassMemberScope.getConstructors(LazyClassMemberScope.kt:504)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.getConstructors(LazyClassDescriptor.java:432)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.resolveMemberHeaders(LazyClassDescriptor.java:656)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.resolveAllHeadersInClasses(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:241)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:214)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.LazyTopDownAnalyzer.analyzeDeclarations$default(LazyTopDownAnalyzer.kt:58)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:127)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:262)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:53)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:113)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:253)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:100)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:58)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:170)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:92)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:434)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:120)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:357)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally$default(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:299)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:118)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:169)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:80)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:622)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:100)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1713)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

If i run Flutter run --verbose it gives me a little more detail but i cant get any further along troubleshooting this error. Tried changing in my IDE but no option to change the target from 1.7/1.8?

```
> Task :ble_hrv:compileDebugKotlin
[        ] 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.7) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 1.8) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
```

Any help greatly appreciated!